# retain only the domain name of url and print in bibliography as organisation

Tags: urls

How can I define a command to retain only the domain name of a link e.g. http://www.google.com/search?=bang will give only google.com and display it as organisation field for a url reference?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is really a non-trivial request, and I strongly advise to fill out the `organization` field manually (your least problem is capitalisation of the organization's name: you would not want `url = {http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/moonfact.html}` to come out as `organization = {nasa}`, but `organization = {NASA}`).

Some more or less useful solution as a proof of concept with `biblatex` and `biber`.

This sourcemap goes into the preamble.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \step[fieldsource=url, match=\regexp{^((?:f|ht)tps?://)?(?:www\.)?([^/]+)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=organization, fieldvalue={$2}]
    }
  }
}
```

It tries to extract the domain part of a URL from the `url` field and maps it to the `organization` field. Since getting rid of sub-domains is not a trivial task especially if you take into account that there are TLDs like `.co.uk`, `.info`, `.de`, `.com` etc., these are still included.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ELECTRONIC{MEMSnet,
  title = {What is {MEMS}?},
  url = {http://www.memsnet.org/mems/what_is.html},
  urldate = {2013-12-01},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \step[fieldsource=url, match=\regexp{^((?:f|ht)tps?://)?(?:www\.)?([^/]+)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=organization, fieldvalue={$2}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{MEMSnet,wilde,markey}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Both issues mentioned above can be observed here: One would probably want to see `MEMSnet` instead of `memsnet.org`, and `CTAN` instead of `tug.ctan.org`.